# Unable to find the installed package

Tags: managed-package, package

I created my first Lightning component and created a package , 
then upload that package and had a link available for installation.

Then I tried to install that with a different organization and successfully installed and I can see that on installed package list but I dont know how I can have access to that .
It was available under custom when edit a contact page while I was doing development but now as a package it is not . not sure what I did wrong .

Answer (score 0):

if you got the message for successful Installation, then go to the Target Org 
Click on Setup, Type Installed package in the search box and click on the installed packages. Also,make sure you have an admin profile

[image]